# Movimiento del escenario y detección del borde de un canvas en javascript con vehículo

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, canvas, scroll

a ver si podéis ayudarme,,estoy creando un jeep que se mueve por un escenario, la cosa es que quiero que se detecte la colisión con los bordes del canvas del vehículo y que se detenga.

también hay un problema, el jeep debe moverse por un escenario, que no es ni mas ni menos que una fotografía, lo que quiero es que al moverse el jeep también lo haga la fotografía debajo de él, en todo caso no lo he logrado resolver, he estado mirando codigo y bueno.

a ver que se os ocurre, os paso el js

```js
 "use strict";

 const clamp = (n, lo, hi) => n < lo ? lo : n > hi ? hi : n;
 const tau = Math.PI * 2;
 const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.style.background = "#eee";
 canvas.style.background="url('SUELO.png')";
 canvas.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
 const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 var img = new Image();
 img.src = 'JEEP1.png';
 var img2 = new Image();
 img2.src = 'SUELO.png';



 document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 canvas.height = 400;
 canvas.width = 400;
 const map = {
  height: 1000,
  width: 2000,
  images: ctx.drawImage(img2,10,10),
};



const viewport = {};

let kbd;
let ship;
//Let scenario;//variable de fondo

/*const scenario=function=(x,y,size,img2){//variable de prueba
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = size;
  this.radius = size;
  this.img2 = img2;
}*/


const Ship = function (x, y, angle, size, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.ax = 0;
  this.ay = 0;
  this.rv = 0;
  this.angle = angle;
  this.accelerationAmount = 0.01;
  this.decelerationAmount = 0.01;
  this.friction = 0.9;
  this.rotationSpd = 0.0020;
  this.size = size;
  this.radius = size;
  this.color = color;
};

Ship.prototype = {
 //aceleración del vehiculo 
 accelerate: function (backwards) {
   if (backwards) {
    this.ax -= this.decelerationAmount;
    this.ay -= this.decelerationAmount;
  }
  else {
   this.ax += this.accelerationAmount;
   this.ay += this.accelerationAmount;
 }
},
//movimiento del vehiculo
move: function () {
 this.angle += this.rv;
 this.vx += this.ax;
 this.vy += this.ay;
 this.x += this.vx * Math.cos(this.angle);
 this.y += this.vy * Math.sin(this.angle);
 this.ax *= this.friction;
 this.ay *= this.friction;
 this.vx *= this.friction;
 this.vy *= this.friction;
 this.rv *= this.friction;
},

  //rota el vehiculo
  rotate: function (dir) {
   if (dir === "left") {
      this.rv -= this.rotationSpd;
    }
    else if (dir === "right") {
      this.rv += this.rotationSpd;
    }
  },
  
  draw: function (ctx, viewport) {
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(this.x + viewport.x,
      this.y + viewport.y);
   ctx.rotate(this.angle);
   ctx.lineWidth = 3;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
   ctx.lineTo(this.size / 1.2, 0);
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
   ctx.drawImage(img,-25,-25,50,50)
  // ctx.drawImage(img2,25,-20,2000,2000)


   
   

   ctx.fillRect(

    this.size / -2, 
    this.size / -2, 
     // this.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 10, 10),
     this.size, 
     this.size

     );
  /*  ctx.strokeRect(
      this.size / -1, 
      this.size / -1, 
      this.size, 
      this.size
      );*/

      ctx.restore();
    }
  };


  (function init() {
    kbd = {
      ctrl: false,
      u: false, 
      d: false,
      l: false,
      r: false
    };

    ship = new Ship(
      canvas.width / 2, 
      canvas.height / 2, 
      10, 10, "transparent",


      );
  })();

//mover jeep hacia abajo
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
 if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    kbd.l = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    kbd.u = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    kbd.r = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    kbd.d = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    kbd.space = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

//mover jeep hacia arriba
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
 if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    kbd.l = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    kbd.u = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    kbd.r = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    kbd.d = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    kbd.space  = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});


(function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  if (kbd.u) { ship.accelerate();     }
  if (kbd.d) { ship.accelerate(true); }
  if (kbd.l) { ship.rotate("left");   }
  if (kbd.r) { ship.rotate("right");  }

  ship.move();
  
  viewport.x = clamp(
   -ship.x + canvas.width / 2, 
    canvas.width - map.width, 0
    );
  viewport.y = clamp(
   -ship.y + canvas.height / 2, 
    canvas.height - map.height, 0
    );
  
  for (let i = 0; i < map.height; i += 50) {
   for (let j = 0; j < map.width; j += 50) {
    if ((i / 50 + j / 50) & 1) {  
        ctx.drawImage(img2,-25,-25,50,50)
        ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + (100 - (i + j) / 10) + ")";
        //ctx.fillStyle = ctx.drawImage(img,-25,-25,500,500);//EXPERIMENTOS
        ctx.fillRect(j + viewport.x, i + viewport.y, 13,13);
      }
    }
  }
  
  ship.draw(ctx, viewport);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
})();
```

```css
body { 
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}

html, body { 
  height: 98%; 
}

body > canvas { 
  margin: auto; 
  border: 4px solid #222; 
}

body > div {
  background: black;
  color: red;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>arrow keys to move</div>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
 
 body { 
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}
html, body { 
  height: 98%; 
}
body > canvas { 
  margin: auto; 
  border: 4px solid #222; 
}
body > div {
  /*background: #222;*/
  /*color: #fff;*/
  padding: 2px;
 /* background-image: url("JEEP1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

 
  <script src="jeep.js"></script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

os adjunto el github del proyecto para que podáis verlo bien

https://github.com/MMBBAA/jeep-v1

Comment: Hola buenas, que es lo que has intentado hacer?

Comment: Ok, pero que has intentado para detectar el movimento?

Comment: Más bien estoy intentando, lo que pretendo es que el vehículo se detenga cuando detecte el borde del canvas y colisione, y por otro lado y lo que más me está preocupando es que el suelo, un terreno, se mueva conforme el vehículo avanza, así logro el efecto de movimiento. El problema es que lo que quiero que se mueva es una imagen, que se desplace, y en esas estoy.

Comment: Alberto, dime algo como: he intendo mover la imagen, y cuando la suma de la variable x es 100 lo paro o algo asi, que podamos ver que has intentado y que no. Gracias ;)

Comment: Tu defines el ancho del canvas y tu defines el ancho de la imagen de jeep. Cuando la imagen del Jeep + los espacios que le des, sea = ancho de canvas ...PUM. Puedes hacer algo parecido con el suelo.
Cuando lo tengas mas adelantado nos explicas que has intentado asi te podremos ayudar todos! ;)

Comment: OK, tomo nota del enfoque de la colisión, voy a hacer la función para detectar la colisión, pero aún no logro hacer que el fondo se mueva, veré como hacer.

Comment: Para el suelo, si mueve el coche x mueve el suelo x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo detectando la posicion del jeep en el `canvas` 
agregando esta linea a `ship.draw` para evitar dibujar fuera del canvas!

```
    if (this.x <= 20)
        this.x = 20;

    if (this.y <= 20)
        this.y = 20;

    if (this.x >= map.width-20)
        this.x = map.width-20;

    if (this.y >= map.height-20)
        this.y = map.height-20;
```

y para que el fondo se mueva solo debes redibujar la imagen [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) agregando esta linea a `ship.move`.

```
map.images =ctx.drawImage(img2,this.x,this.y,canvas.width,canvas.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

```js
 "use strict";

 const clamp = (n, lo, hi) => n < lo ? lo : n > hi ? hi : n;
 const tau = Math.PI * 2;
 const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.focus();
 canvas.style.background = "#eee";
 /*canvas.style.background="url('SUELO.png')";
 canvas.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';*/
 const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 var img = new Image();
 img.src = 'https://github.com/MMBBAA/jeep-v1/blob/master/JEEP1.png?raw=true';
 var img2 = new Image();
 img2.src = 'https://github.com/MMBBAA/jeep-v1/blob/master/SUELO.png?raw=true';

 document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 canvas.height = 400;
 canvas.width = 400;
 const map = {
  height: 1000 - canvas.height,
  width: 1000 - canvas.width,
  images: ctx.drawImage(img2,0,0),
};



const viewport = {};

let kbd;
let ship;
//Let scenario;//variable de fondo

/*const scenario=function=(x,y,size,img2){//variable de prueba
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = size;
  this.radius = size;
  this.img2 = img2;
}*/


const Ship = function (x, y, angle, size, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.ax = 0;
  this.ay = 0;
  this.rv = 0;
  this.angle = angle;
  this.accelerationAmount = 0.01;
  this.decelerationAmount = 0.01;
  this.friction = 0.9;
  this.rotationSpd = 0.0020;
  this.size = size;
  this.radius = size;
  this.color = color;
};

Ship.prototype = {
 //aceleración del vehiculo 
 accelerate: function (backwards) {
   if (backwards) {
    this.ax -= this.decelerationAmount;
    this.ay -= this.decelerationAmount;
  }
  else {
   this.ax += this.accelerationAmount;
   this.ay += this.accelerationAmount;
 }
},
//movimiento del vehiculo
move: function () {
 map.images =ctx.drawImage(img2,this.x,this.y,canvas.width,canvas.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 this.angle += this.rv;
 this.vx += this.ax;
 this.vy += this.ay;
 this.x += this.vx * Math.cos(this.angle);
 this.y += this.vy * Math.sin(this.angle);
 this.ax *= this.friction;
 this.ay *= this.friction;
 this.vx *= this.friction;
 this.vy *= this.friction;
 this.rv *= this.friction;
},

  //rota el vehiculo
  rotate: function (dir) {
   if (dir === "left") {
      this.rv -= this.rotationSpd;
    }
    else if (dir === "right") {
      this.rv += this.rotationSpd;
    }
  },
  
  draw: function (ctx, viewport) {


    if (this.x <= 20)
        this.x = 20;

    if (this.y <= 20)
        this.y = 20;

    if (this.x >= map.width-20)
        this.x = map.width-20;

    if (this.y >= map.height-20)
        this.y = map.height-20;

   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(this.x + viewport.x, this.y + viewport.y);
   ctx.rotate(this.angle);
   ctx.lineWidth = 3;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
   ctx.lineTo(this.size / 1.2, 0);
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
   ctx.drawImage(img,-25,-25,50,50)
  // ctx.drawImage(img2,25,-20,2000,2000)


   
   

   ctx.fillRect(

    this.size / -2, 
    this.size / -2, 
     // this.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 10, 10),
     this.size, 
     this.size

     );
  /*  ctx.strokeRect(
      this.size / -1, 
      this.size / -1, 
      this.size, 
      this.size
      );*/

      ctx.restore();
    }
  };


  (function init() {
    kbd = {
      ctrl: false,
      u: false, 
      d: false,
      l: false,
      r: false
    };

    ship = new Ship(
      canvas.width / 2, 
      canvas.height / 2, 
      10, 10, "transparent",


      );
  })();

//mover jeep hacia abajo
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
 if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    kbd.l = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    kbd.u = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    kbd.r = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    kbd.d = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    kbd.space = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

//mover jeep hacia arriba
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
 if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    kbd.l = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    kbd.u = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    kbd.r = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    kbd.d = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    kbd.space  = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});


(function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  if (kbd.u) { ship.accelerate();     }
  if (kbd.d) { ship.accelerate(true); }
  if (kbd.l) { ship.rotate("left");   }
  if (kbd.r) { ship.rotate("right");  }

  ship.move();
  
  viewport.x = clamp(
   -ship.x + canvas.width / 2, 
    canvas.width - map.width, 0
    );
  viewport.y = clamp(
   -ship.y + canvas.height / 2, 
    canvas.height - map.height, 0
    );
  
  for (let i = 0; i < map.height; i += 50) {
   for (let j = 0; j < map.width; j += 50) {
    if ((i / 50 + j / 50) & 1) {  
        // ctx.drawImage(img2,-25,-25,50,50) 
        ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + (100 - (i + j) / 10) + ")";
        //ctx.fillStyle = ctx.drawImage(img,-25,-25,500,500);//EXPERIMENTOS
        ctx.fillRect(j + viewport.x, i + viewport.y, 13,13);
      }
    }
  }
  
  ship.draw(ctx, viewport);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
})();
```

```css
body { 
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}

html, body { 
  height: 98%; 
}

body > canvas { 
  margin: auto; 
  border: 4px solid #222; 
}

body > div {
  background: black;
  color: red;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>arrow keys to move</div>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
 
 body { 
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}
html, body { 
  height: 98%; 
}
body > canvas { 
  margin: auto; 
  border: 4px solid #222; 
}
body > div {
  /*background: #222;*/
  /*color: #fff;*/
  padding: 2px;
 /* background-image: url("JEEP1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

 
  <script src="jeep.js"></script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

he investigado un poco y he logrado sacar un juego, aquí podeis mirarlo.

Se podría haber hecho con muchos mas objetos y reducir muchísimo código, pero en todo caso es una buena base para ver colisiones, como funciona un canvas y demás.

Aquí os paso enlace.

Un saludo a todos y gracias por las respuestas, han sido de mucha utilidad (he encontrado muchas soluciones para movimiento de escenario y también para cambio de mapa si se desea, pero en este caso he tomado el camino de un mapa estático, pero lo otro también se sacarlo adelante)

El juego:

https://github.com/MMBBAA/Videogame-Mars-Jeep-V1